# Creating combinations of observations in SAS

Tags: sas, combinations

I need to figure out how to tabulate all possible combinations of data in a dataset.  I have a dataset where each person has 2 rows, one row for an activity score and one row for a total score on a test.  There are variables for the score at each visit.  A person may have anywhere between 1 to 5 visits.  I am looking for all possible combinations of the scores for a given person for each score.

For example, here is code to generate the sample data structure.

```
data example;
  input name $ type $ visit1-visit5;
    datalines;
    Bob activity 10 13 16 . .
    Bob total 13 19 17 . .
    John activity 11 20 25 20 21
    John total 13 15 17 19 22
    Steve activity 6 . . . .
    Steve total 9 . . . . .
    ;
run;
```

I would like to have a dataset that would give me a structure as follows:

```
Bob activity 10 13
Bob activity 10 16
Bob activity 13 16
Bob total    13 19
Bob total    13 17
Bob total    19 17
John (rows for all possible combinations)
Steve - would have no rows, since he only has one visit (no combinations possible)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For N choose 2 and the output structure you want a couple of nested DO's will suffice.

```
data example;
   input name $ type $ visit1-visit5;
   datalines;
Bob activity 10 13 16 . .
Bob total 13 19 17 . .
John activity 11 20 25 20 21
John total 13 15 17 19 22
Steve activity 6 . . . .
Steve total 9 . . . . .
;;;;
   run;
data by2;
   set example;
   array v[*] visit:;
   n=n(of v[*]);
   do i = 1 to n;
      col1 = v[i];
      do j = i + 1 to n;
         col2 = v[j];
         output;
         end;
      end;
   drop i j visit:;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```